# Export job from Talend open studio TOS via commandline/eclipse

Tags: talend

I have a decent number of talend jobs which have been over sometime using TOS (talend open studio). Currently i am using tos 5.6.1. we have now reached a phase in our project where we would like to get jobs exported into .jar files via some commandline/automated way from talend open studio, as against using Menu option of export/build job. is there any way i can do this in TOS or only option i have is to go for Enterprise version of talend (TIS)

Answer (score 0):

so far to date this functionality is only pat of the TIS versions.

something i have been playing with is exporting the SRC from talend to SVN, then pull and build using Jenkins, but you still need to do the initial build via the TOS